# Data mining, curse of dimensionality

Tags: data-mining

Let's say I have a dataset represented as a matrix X, of dimensions n x m, with m high. I would like to quickly reduce the dimension m such that the objects in each row in X preserve distances to each other. One way to accomplish this would be to:
create a mapping matrix A by initializing it with all 0's and then randomly choosing 1/6 of its values to be +1 and 1/6 of its values to be -1, and then multiply X by A.

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are preserving the distances, then you are also preserving the curse of dimensionality. The distances will still all be too similar to be useful...